# What is the SPM Bundle.module equivalent in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift-package-manager

I need to access Swift Package Manager's Bundle.module equivalent in objective-c. I've tried the Bundle.module in Objective-c but no luck. This is how we access in Swift:

```
public let settingsURL = Bundle.module.url(forResource: “settings”, withExtension: “plist”)
```

Any guess what my be the equivalent in objective-c?

Here is the [Apple Documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/bundling_resources_with_a_swift_package).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Solution

Oh!? Sometimes things get so weird between these two beautiful languages. I found the solution:

```
NSString *path = [SWIFTPM_MODULE_BUNDLE pathForResource:@"settings" ofType:@"plist"];
```

So simple right? :)

For more information, please check the [related proposal (SE-0271)](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0271-package-manager-resources.md).

> For Objective-C, the build system will add a preprocessor define
> called SWIFTPM_MODULE_BUNDLE which can be used to access the bundle
> from any .m file.

Comment: If you landed here because of a `use of undeclared identifier 'SWIFTPM_MODULE_BUNDLE'` error when running `swift test`, know that's [known issue with Swift Package Manager](https://href.li/?https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/issues/4500).

Comment: NOTE: You must target platform `.iOS(.v14)`+ to get this macro